# Filepaths containing ampersand (&) character

Tags: javascript, query-string, special-characters, filepath, ampersand

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app which includes the facility for clients to upload/download documents from a folder on the server.

I'm having a problem with people uploading file names containing an ampersand character (possibly other characters too, this is the only one I've discovered so far).

The result is I'm getting javascript redirects looking something like:

```
window.location.href = 'MyController/DownloadDocument?filename=Dog & Cat.pdf';
```

which obviously doesn't work.

What's the easiest work around for something like this? Is there any way to escape the ampersand in the query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`encodeUriComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (which will also fix the problem of the spaces, which aren't allowed in URIs)

Comment: Ok, I'm now getting the filename as **Dog &amp; Cat.pdf** in my MVC controller. Is there an ASP.NET equivalent for un-encoding server side?

Comment: That is an HTML encoding which you shouldn't see in JavaScript. It sounds like you are running the JS through an HTML encoding library before serving it to the browser. Decoding it isn't the solution, it shouldn't be encoded that way in the first place, so stop doing that.

Comment: I'm not manually encoding it anywhere, so I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I've fixed it with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(filename);` server side.